# How to start `MYSQL` service in wamp server?

Tags: wampserver

MYSQL service interupted the color of wamp icon turning from orange to green, in menu when i click `mysql.log` file it says cant find `mysql.log`.How to fix this? How i can start this service it is really frustrating please help me?

Comment: Your question is REALLY unclear. Please edit your question and make it plain what actually is happening.

Comment: Look at the Windows Event Viewer for Error messages from Apache or MYSQL

Comment: Do yo have a Service called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` when you look at the services snapin?

Comment: yes when i look into the service snapin i have this service `wampmysqld64` but its status is empty but `wampapache` service has running status. So, how to make `wampmysql64` service run?

Comment: look when i try to start this service it popped an `Error:1067` msg which says the process terminated unexpectedly. Now what should i do?

Comment: - Do you have another MYSQL Server running?

Comment: Look at the mysql error log `wampmanager -> MYSQL->Error log` also look at the Windows Event Viewer for Error Mesages from MYSQL

Comment: No i did not have another MYSQL server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86513/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-sony).

Comment: i did not have error log in MYSQL instead i only have my.ini and mysql log

Comment: Sorry I had to leave yesterday. Did you solve this after our chat yesterday?

Comment: yes i did man i'm sorry but its all about your first question which is wheather u have another mysql application or not? although i uninstalled it before ur question but some of its files were still there so i deleted them manually and now it works fine thank u pal, i really appreciate it what u r doing here ,helping out us.

Comment: @RiggsFolly man i really need your help, I install mail server in order to use php function mail() in order to send mails to my gmail account but the server sent emails to only microsoft outlook app which is sinked to my gmail account but emails do not appearing on  my gmail account

Comment: Sorry this site does not work like that, you have to ask another question. Make sure you add what mail server you installed. Also its very unlikely that a real mail server like gmail will accept mail from an unknown mail server installed on your PC. Otherwise we would not be able to move for SPAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of WAMPServers MYSQL finding old `my.ini` files left on the system by other attempts to install MYSQL manually.

If you try to install MYSQL manually specifically if you use the `.msi` install or the MYSQL Workbench install that comes with a copy of MYSQL Server, it puts the `my.ini` into `\windows\system32`. This is one of the folders that MYSQL searches for its `my.ini` file, prior to searching its own `bin` folder.

WAMPServer is very tidy and does not place any of its files outside the `\wamp\` folder structure, this is so you can switch versions of MYSQL, which is one of its big benefits, so it i safe to delete these other `.my.ini` files.